# setTimeOut is not working inside for loop Javascript React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting

So basically I'm building a visual sorting algorithm app with react, I am implementing bubble sort and the general idea is to generate an array from numbers 1 to 50, shuffle it and the sort it using the bubble sort method. The problem right now is that I want a 500 ms delay each time i'm swapping two values so the user can appreciate how the algorithm works but setTimeOut does not seem to work inside a for loop.

```
function doBubbleSort() {
const animationsArray = document.getElementsByClassName('col-itself');
let arr = this.state.numbers;
console.log(arr);
let len = arr.length;

for (let i = 0; i < len ; i++) {
    for(let j = 0 ; j < len - i - 1; j++){
        if (arr[j].value > arr[j + 1].value) {
            let temp = arr[j].value;
            arr[j].value = arr[j+1].value;
            arr[j+1].value = temp;

            const barOneStyle = animationsArray[j].style;
            const barTwoStyle = animationsArray[j+1].style;
            const barOneHeight = arr[j].value * 3 + 'px';
            const barTwoHeight = arr[j+1].value * 3 + 'px';
            const color = '#FF5722';

            setTimeout(() => {
                barOneStyle.backgroundColor = color;
                barOneStyle.height = barOneHeight;
                barTwoStyle.backgroundColor = color;
                barTwoStyle.height = barTwoHeight;
            }, 500);
        }
    }
}
return arr;}
```

The behavior right now is that the app waits for 500 ms, then executes all of the code at once, so it goes from unsorted to totally sorted 500ms after.
I hope you can help me.

Comment: I would rather store all steps done to sort the array and display them using the setTimeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've written is queueing up a bunch of functions that will run in 500ms from when your outer for loop has executed.

One approach you could take is to keep track of the timeout and increment it by 500 on each iteration of the loop.

```
let timeout = 500;
for ...
  for ..
    // call setTiemout with your code 
    setTimeout(/* your function */, timeout);
    // increment timeout
    timeout += 500;
```

So the first iteration of the loop would call your timeout callback in 500ms, the second in 1000ms, the third in 1500ms, and so on.

Your code with this approach:

```
function doBubbleSort() {
const animationsArray = document.getElementsByClassName('col-itself');
let arr = this.state.numbers;
console.log(arr);
let len = arr.length;
let timeout = 500;

for (let i = 0; i < len ; i++) {
    for(let j = 0 ; j < len - i - 1; j++){
        if (arr[j].value > arr[j + 1].value) {
            let temp = arr[j].value;
            arr[j].value = arr[j+1].value;
            arr[j+1].value = temp;

            const barOneStyle = animationsArray[j].style;
            const barTwoStyle = animationsArray[j+1].style;
            const barOneHeight = arr[j].value * 3 + 'px';
            const barTwoHeight = arr[j+1].value * 3 + 'px';
            const color = '#FF5722';

            setTimeout(() => {
                barOneStyle.backgroundColor = color;
                barOneStyle.height = barOneHeight;
                barTwoStyle.backgroundColor = color;
                barTwoStyle.height = barTwoHeight;
            }, timeout);
            timeout += 500;
        }
    }
}
return arr;}
```

Comment: Thanks man, you really helped me here, It totally works with the example that you provided me with. I didn't know that setTimeOut worked like that.
Thanks!

Comment: Or, forget the loop altogether and have the reoccuring timer (via `setInterval()` or a recursive `setTimeout()`) take care of the looping functionality.